# Communicating between python and arduino via serial port, only receives zero

Tags: python, arduino, pyserial

I am trying to communicate via my laptop to my arduino using the USB serial port. I am using Python 3.6, with the serial package. The simplified version of my Python code is :

```
import serial
import time
with serial.Serial(port="COM3", baudrate=9600) as ser:
    time.sleep(2)
    while True:
        x, y, angle = detectAndDisplay(frame, face_cascade, eyes_cascade)
        if x is not None:
            ser.write((str(x * 100 // 177) + "/n").encode())
            ser.write((str(y * 100 // 133) + "/n").encode())
        if cv.waitKey(10) == 27:
            break
```

Where the function detectAndDisplay() returns three int values. The values x, y are scaled to be between 0 and 180. I want to send the values x, y to the arduino, which has the following simplified code:

```
#include <PID_v1.h>
#include <Servo.h>
Servo Servo_1; 
Servo Servo_2;
double Setpoint_1 = 90;
double Input_1;
double Output_1;

double Setpoint_2 = 90;
double Input_2;
double Output_2;

double Kp_1 = 0.022;
double Ki_1 = 0.012;
double Kd_1 = 0;

double Kp_2 = 0.032;
double Ki_2 = 0.022;
double Kd_2 = 0;

PID PID1(&Input_1, &Output_1, &Setpoint_1, Kp_1, Ki_1, Kd_1, DIRECT);
PID PID2(&Input_2, &Output_2, &Setpoint_2, Kp_2, Ki_2, Kd_2, DIRECT);

int serialCount = 0;
int serialInArray[2];
int posX = 90;
int posY = 90;
int errorX;
int errorY;

void setup() {
    Serial.begin(9600);
    Servo_1.attach(32);
    Servo_2.attach(34);
    PID1.SetMode(AUTOMATIC);
    PID1.SetSampleTime(1);
    PID1.SetOutputLimits(-35, 35);

    PID2.SetMode(AUTOMATIC);
    PID2.SetSampleTime(1);
    PID2.SetOutputLimits(-35, 35);
    Servo_1.write(90);
    Servo_2.write(90);
}

void loop() {
    while(Serial.available() == 0);
    serialInArray[serialCount] = (Serial.read());
    serialCount++;
    if (serialCount > 1){
        Input_1 = serialInArray[1];
        Input_2 = serialInArray[0];
        PID1.Compute();
        PID2.Compute();
        posX = posX + Output_2;
        posY = posY + Output_1;
        Servo_1.write(posX);
        Servo_2.write(posY);
        serialCount = 0;
    }
}
```

Where I will use the values of posX and posY as input for servo motors. However, what I notice is that input is received on the arduino because it starts doing something as soon as the python script is started. However, the servo motors start turning to zero as soon as the input is received. This behavior is independent of the value that I am sending. What am I missing or what am I doing wrong?

Comment: You are writing values as strings: the value 123 produces the output characters "1", "2", and "3", followed by a newline.  But you are reading a single character for each value, and aren't prepared to receive newlines at all.  Either approach is workable, you just need to agree at both ends!

Comment: Thanks, that was indeed the mistake I was making. Fixed it, and now it is working!